# Can I have a self-hosted VPN on my Linux host?

Tags: linux, vpn, hosts

I have a account on a Linux host, is it possible to install a VPN (or opneVPN) on my server? or does it require special kinds of servers?

Comment: Root access y/n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your hosting company.

If this is small hosting company - you can ask them to configure VPN for you but this may be very problematic and expensive. VPN is very custom service in typical hosting company.

Even if you have VPS with root access - you may have to ask admins in hosting company to create virtual TUN/TAP devices for you, replace/update kernel or something like this, because VPS typically share linux kernel with other VPS on same machine.

If VPN server service has some data transfer limits - typical transfer counters probably will not work with TUN/TAP devices properly. There are many other problems with VPN on hosting server.

If you want to configure VPN without ANY problems - you need dedicated hosting - real machine, or normal VPN service from company who offers VPN services.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can install it right there. However, if you have a user in the server, you need root access to do it.

Check linux distributions build specifically for that purpose.

Comment: He needs root access AND full kernel control for VPN. Take a look at my answer.